# How to handle Long-Running Task with Apache Camel

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I have a Camel root that executes a HTTP-call in the middle of the root to enrich the main objects in the exchange:

```
     <route>
        <from uri="http:somerestcall"/> 
        <bean ref="jsonUtils" method="someJsonConversion"/>
        <split>
            <simple>body</simple>
            <!-- this is the one -->
            <bean ref="enrichmentBean" method="someAdditionalHTTPCall"/>
        </split>
        <to uri="writetosomequeue"/>
    </route>
```

I know Camel provides a lot of [asynchronous functionality](https://camel.apache.org/async.html) - **how do I best utilize Camel to deal with the potentially long-running HTTP-call in the middle of the route, without having Threads stuck in sleep mode?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is somewhat application specific, if your thread is waiting on the response from the HTTP request and needs that information to continue, I would just make the process more parallel and let the thread do nothing.  If the thread isn't working its not wasting real cpu anyway.  However, if your process can continue to work while waiting on the http call, then I recommend sending it off to a seda route to do your lookup call and then store the results somewhere you can access later like a concurrent map you can reference for results based off some sort of key.

```
<route>
    <from uri="http:somerestcall"/> 
    <bean ref="jsonUtils" method="someJsonConversion"/>
    <split>
        <simple>body</simple>
        <!-- this is the one -->
        <to uri="seda:concurrentFun" />
    </split>
    <to uri="Lots of other work" />
    <bean ref="StorageBean" method="enrichFromStoreAndRemove" />
    <to uri="writetosomequeue"/>
</route>

<route>
    <From uri="seda:concurrentFun" />
    <bean ref="enrichmentBean" method="someAdditionalHTTPCall"/>
    <bean ref="StorageBean" method="store" />
</route>
```